# Get product value on cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

```
Array
(
    [1a0421df7401f1b79616141d5a4e223a] => Array
        (
            [rental_data] => Array
                (
                    [pickup_date] => 2017/10/02
                    [dropoff_date] => 2017/10/05
                    [rental_days_and_costs] => Array
                        (
                            [days] => 3
                            [hours] => 0
                            [booked_dates] => Array
                                (
                                    [formatted] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 2017/10/02
                                            [1] => 2017/10/03
                                            [2] => 2017/10/04
                                        )

                                    [iso] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 1506902400
                                            [1] => 1506988800
                                            [2] => 1507075200
                                        )

                                )

                            [cost] => 123.75
                            [due_payment] => 251.25
                        )

                    [max_hours_late] => 0
                )

            [product_id] => 181
            [variation_id] => 0
            [variation] => Array
                (
                )

            [quantity] => 1
            [line_total] => 123.75
            [line_subtotal] => 123.75
            [line_tax] => 0
            [line_subtotal_tax] => 0
            [line_tax_data] => Array
                (
                    [total] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [subtotal] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [data] => WC_Product_Redq_Rental Object
                (
                    [object_type:protected] => product
                    [post_type:protected] => product
                    [cache_group:protected] => products
                    [data:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Spelga House (sleeps 10)
                            [slug] => spelga-house-accomodation
                            [date_created] => WC_DateTime Object
                                (
                                    [utc_offset:protected] => 0
                                    [date] => 2016-02-06 10:36:40.000000
                                    [timezone_type] => 3
                                    [timezone] => Europe/London
                                )

                            [date_modified] => WC_DateTime Object
                                (
                                    [utc_offset:protected] => 0
                                    [date] => 2017-09-25 13:06:09.000000
                                    [timezone_type] => 3
                                    [timezone] => Europe/London
                                )

                            [status] => publish
                            [featured] => 
                            [catalog_visibility] => visible
                            [description] => A large detached, recently renovated high spec modern house, previously owned by the water board and maintains its characteristics. Spelga House has spectacular views of the surrounding Mourne Mountains, and only seven miles from the lively resort town of Newcastle and three miles from Hilltown. The house sits in front of the dam wall, on top of the Mournes, and is
```

i want to get the value of `[due_payment]` array in woocommerce cart page and `[1a0421df7401f1b79616141d5a4e223a]` root name change each time for each product how i get this any help?  I am using the rental and booking woocommerce plugin and product type is rental product in woocommerce I am beginners for the array and plugin customozation  I also search for that but i didn,t get any idea how i get the value of `[due_payment]` array . please guide me how i do that

Comment: Use `foreach()` then.

Comment: where i use foreach please guide me

Comment: global $woocommerce;
    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

        foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
            ?>
            <pre>
            <?php
            print_r($items);
            ?>
            </pre>
            <?php
        }

Comment: i am using like that to get this array

Comment: `foreach($values as $arr){ echo $arr['rental_data']['rental_days_and_costs']['due_payment'];}`

Comment: global $woocommerce;
    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

        foreach($values as $arr){ 
            echo $arr['rental_data']['rental_days_and_costs']['due_payment'];
                    }

Comment: its not working

Comment: its woking my fault foreach loop problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply one more `foreach()` like below:-

```
global $woocommerce; 
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();    
foreach($items as $item => $values) {  
    foreach($values as $arr){ //apply one-more foreach()
      echo $arr['rental_data']['rental_days_and_costs']['due_payment'];‌​‌
    }
}
```

Note:- You can curtale thses two lines:-

```
global $woocommerce; 
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
```

Into one:-

```
$items = WC()->cart->get_cart();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of doing it, using the array key. Will not need 2 foreach loop.

```
$cart_items = WC()->cart->get_cart(); 
foreach( $cart_items as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {  
      echo $cart_items[$cart_item_key]['rental_data']['rental_days_and_costs']['due_payment'];‌​‌
}
```

and yet another way of doing it. This time without the foreach loop.

```
$cart_items = WC()->cart->get_cart();
if ( is_array( $cart_items ) && !empty( $cart_items ) ) {
    $cart_item_keys = array_keys($cart_items);
    echo $cart_items[$cart_item_keys[0]]['rental_data']['rental_days_and_costs']['due_payment'];‌​‌
}
```